# Wordpress debugging Unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM

Tags: php, wordpress

Having issues with Wordpress error Unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting :: (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp-content/themes/theme/functions.php on line 5

My functions.php code:

```
<?php
// Navigation Menus
register_nav_menus (array(
  'primary' => --('Primaty Menu')
)); 
?>
```

Comment: did you Google that error? it's quite descriptive.

Comment: yes I did but haven't found a fitting solution

Comment: @MendyKastiel Those dashes were incorrect, but they shouldn't be removed. They should have been underscores, such as `__('Primary Menu')` which integrates with WordPress' [`__($text)`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_2) translations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code contains two extraneous dashes, amongst other things that look a little strange.  Removing the dashes allows the parser to continue.

```
<?php
// Navigation Menus
register_nav_menus (array(
      'primary' => ('Primaty Menu')
));
```

Incidentally, you don't have "unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM", you have the parser ***expecting*** one.  ("PAAMAYIM NEKUDOTAYIM" is Hebrew for "double colon").

As Kirk Beard points out, you actually should've had two **underscores** where you had hyphens.

Comment: thanks now I understand lol.

Comment: You're welcome.  Now would be a good time to click that this is an accepted answer ;-)

Comment: where in the code should I put the "double colon" ?

Comment: It's not telling you that you must add one; it's saying that as it was interpreting what you had written, it was expecting one as the only valid way to continue at that point (after reading the two hyphens, I guess).  Since you removed them you probably don't need them.  Double colons are the "scope resolution operator" and generally used to refer to a static method or property (see http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php)

Comment: See also Kirk Beard's comment for enlightenment about the problem behind the issue.